# How many times - on a specified date - a DVD recorder was used?

Tags: windows-vista, logging, compact-disc, history, dvd-burning

I'm looking for a way to get to know how many times - on a specified date - a DVD recorder was used (DVD(s) burning).

I'm running Windows Vista. The program used to burn DVD(s) doesn't create any visible logs. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Did you check the event logs for any hardware-related events ?

Comment: If you mean Event Viewer/ Applications and Services Logs/ Hardware Events I have no events there...

Comment: What is the disk buring software? Are you trying to monitor if someone is maliciously copying data to removable media via a dvd rw?

Comment: This will require the use of Windows Server GPO's so may not be applicable to you. Additionally you may not be able to retrospectivly apply this. But regardless it may be of some interest/use to you; http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/08/25/removable-storage-group-policy-and-windows-server-2008-and-windows-vista.aspx If you upgrade from vista then have a look at this for future reference; https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574128.aspx

Comment: The software is BurnAware Free. I'd like to check how many times a DVD was burnt using this program on a specified date.

Comment: I know how much time is needed to burn a data of that size. So one of these two questions answered will tell me whether event of burning that data happened: 1/ how much time was the recorder in a "burning" state on a specified date? or 2/ how much time was BurnAware Free "on"? If 1/ or 2/ < time needed for data of that size to be burnt => data of that size wasn't burnt.

Comment: Looking at my timeline also these questions answered would be very useful: 3/ how many times was the recorder in a "burning" state on a specified date? 4/ what times was BurnAware Free executed on a specified date? When one of these 4 questions is answered: "I'm home!" :-).